# Filtering ranges based on a column from latest model in relationship, then a column from a parent model

Tags: mysql, database, relationship, laravel-5

I have two tables: `auctions` and `bids`. In `auctions`, I have a `start_amount` field and in `bids`, `amount`. Both tables also has `created_at` and `modified_at` timestamp columns. I want to be able to retrieve a list of auctions that match the highest (or latest, however you look at it) bid within a certain range.

I've been working at it for the past week and have only managed to filter based on *all* bids rather than the latest (or minimum) bid (`start_amount` included.) How would I achieve what I am looking for?

The code that I've tried:

```
if (request()->has('bid_range'))
    $auctions->with(['bids' => function ($query) use ($bid_min, $bid_max) {
        $query->whereBetween('amount', [$bid_min, $bid_max])->orWhereBetween('start_amount', [$bid_min, $bid_max])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    }]);
```

Comment: Your code please that you tried?

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Oops, forgot the code. Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you probably trying to do this:

```
select *
from auctions
where exists 
    (select 1 
    from bids 
    where amount > 10 and amount < 20
    and bids.auctions_id = auction.id)
```

So, the Laravel way:

```
DB::table('auctions')
        ->whereExists(function ($query) use ($bid_min, $bid_max) {
            $query->from('bids')
                  ->whereRaw("'amount' > $bid_min and 'amount' < $bid_max")
                  ->whereRaw('bids.auctions_id = auction.id');
        })
        ->get();
```

That's what you want?

Comment: Not quite there. I get this error message: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'auction.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `auctions` where exists (select * from \`bids\` where \`amount\` > 0 and \`amount\` < 1000 and \`bids\`.\`auction_id\` = \`auction\`.\`id\`))` (Maybe there should be a join in there somewhere?)

Comment: `bids`.`auction_id` = `auctions`.`id` ... forgot a s in the end.

Comment: Why do you use `whereRaw()` instead of `where()`? What about sql injections?